# LUA & C++: How to properly use C++ function inside LUA's code

Tags: c++, lua

I'm currently learning using LUA in C++ code. And I came to a point where I cannot figure out how to use C++ function in LUA's code.

I want to create simple function in c++ and then use it in LUA.
My approach is as follows (taken from some tutorials):

In main.cpp:

```
void write(const char* str) {
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
}

static int l_write(lua_State* L) {
    const char* str = lua_tostring(L, 1); // get function argument
    write(str); // calling C++ function with this argument...
    return 0; // nothing to return!
}

int main(){
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L); // load default Lua libs

        if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua")) {
            std::cout<<"Error loading script"<<std::endl;
        }

    lua_pushcfunction(L, l_write);
    lua_setglobal(L, "write"); // this is how function will be named in Lua
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0); // run script
}
```

and in test.lua I've got:

```
write("Hello, world!")
write("The square root of 2 is "..math.sqrt(2))
x = 42
write("We can use variables too, x = "..x)
```

The problem appears in the very beginning of this code: I cannot even a load script `luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua")` returns value 7 (which is as I checked NIME_AGAIN 7 /* temporarily out of resources */).

Everything else works just fine do provided I don't use my custom c++ functions. I can load values from LUAs file normally, can execute function ect.

I suppose that LUA after reading file already compiles it and then finds out name of function that does not exist, namely "write" and returns error in case of reading this file, is it possible? And if so how to resolve this problem, and how to use this feature correctly?

Comment: Lua pushes error messages on its state's stack. This might give you a clue on what exactly went wrong.

Comment: What if you move the `pushcfunction` and `setglobal` before the `loadfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Mhm, guys. It is strange but I did `lua_pop(L, 1)` once, run and then delete it and now its working just fine O.o